# How to break a line at each ';', saved in char*

Tags: c++, csv, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Can sombody help me dividing a line in parts?
I want to break the line at each ';', it is stored in myLine.

Example of a line:
surname firstName;6;7;4;10;5;9;8;3;6;7;4;10;5;9;8;6;7;4;10;5;9;6;7;4;10;5;9;

```
fgets(line[i], LAENGE, datei);          
char* myLine = line[i];
```

I'm thankful for every tip! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c is what you are looking for

Comment: Also, save yourself a lot of trouble and prefer `std::string` to `char*` whereever possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::istringstream iss(myLine);
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::string current;
while(std::getline(iss, current, ';'))
   v.push_back(current));
```

I may have mixed up the parameter order in `getline`